# Parallel builds in Eclipse collide

Tags: eclipse-cdt, multiple-projects, workspace, parallel-builds

I have two C++ Eclipse projects (each pointing to different sandboxes of version-ed code) imported in separate workspaces. I am launching two parallel sessions of eclipse on different machines and then want to build these two projects in parallel. Only one project is open in each workspace, which is the one I want to build in the corresponding sessions. But it seems that as soon as I launch the build of one project, the other on-going build for the first project starts pointing on the source directory of the second project: i.e. when I start building the files in sandbox2 while the build of sandbox1 is on-going, immediately the log build of sandbox1 shows source file paths of the files in sandbox2, and vice-versa.

What could be causing such a behavior, and is there a way to run the two builds in parallel without influencing each other.

Thanks,

Laurent